# MediaPlayer gets stuck in prepare() and never comes out

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Hi I am facing a problem with android MediaPlayer library. I have some invalid media files and some valid media files. MediaPlayer is throwing an error(Calling OnError()) for most of the invalid files. but for some files its getting stuck in prepare() forever. and also after that it starts getting stuck for valid files too. I am not sure why this is happening. MediaPlayer should throw some error for bad media file. below is some code snippet.

```
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        public  String inputFile="/mnt/sdcard/TestFiles/valids.mp3"            
        Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(inputFile));
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
```